# Where I did wrong? Why PropertEditorSupport is not working for me?

Tags: spring, javabeans, propertyeditor

Why I am getting action in `PropertyEditorSupport`? Could anyone please help me here because i am new in Spring. Below is the error report

> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name `'cont'` defined in class path resource [`propertyEdit.xml`]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type [`java.lang.String`] to required type `[Phone]` for property `'phone'`; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: `888-555-1212`
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type `[java.lang.String]` to required type `[Phone]` for property `'phone'`; nested

```
    exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 888-555-1212
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 888-555-1212
        at java.beans.PropertyEditorSupport.setAsText(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertTextValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:326)
        at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:305)
        at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:192)
        at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:138)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:380)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1111)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:861)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:421)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:251)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:156)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:248)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:160)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:287)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:352)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:91)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:75)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:65)
        at ShowContact.main(ShowContact.java:9)
```

I have used java.beans.PropertyEditorSupport in below way

```
public class PhoneEditor extends java.beans.PropertyEditorSupport{
    public void setAsTest(String textValue)
    {
        String stripped = stripNonNumeric(textValue);
        String areaCode=stripped.substring(0,3);
        String prefix=stripped.substring(3,6);
        String number=stripped.substring(6);
        Phone phone=new Phone(areaCode,prefix,number);
        setValue(phone);
    }

    private String stripNonNumeric(String original)
    {
        StringBuffer allNumeric = new StringBuffer();
        for(int i=0; i<original.length(); i++)
        {
            char c=original.charAt(i);
            if(Character.isDigit(c))
            {
                allNumeric.append(c);
            }
        }
        return allNumeric.toString();
    }
}
```

My Config file is below

```
<bean name="customEditorConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomEditorConfigurer">
        <property name="customEditors">
<map>
<entry key="Phone">
<bean id="Phone" class="PhoneEditor">
</bean>
</entry>
</map>
</property>
</bean>

<bean id="cont" class="Contact">
<property name="name" value="Dhirendra"/>
<property name="phone" value="888-555-1212" /> 
</bean> 
</beans>
```

Phone Class is below

```
public class Phone {
private String areaCode;
private String prefix;
private String number;
public Phone(){}
public Phone(String areaCode, String prefix, String number)
{
    this.areaCode=areaCode;
    this.prefix=prefix;
    this.number=number;
}

public String getPhoneNumber()
{
    return prefix+"-"+areaCode+"-"+number;
}

}
```

I am calling in the below way

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomEditorConfigurer;


public class ShowContact {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("propertyEdit.xml");
        Employee employee=(Employee)context.getBean("cont");
        employee.PrintEmpDetails();

    }

}
```

Below is my Contact class which is calling

```
public class Contact implements Employee {
private Phone phone;
private String name;
    public void setPhone(Phone phone) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.phone=phone;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.name=name;
    }

    public void PrintEmpDetails()
    {
        System.out.println("Name of Employee :"+ name);
        System.out.println("Contact Number of Employee :"+ phone.getPhoneNumber());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In `PhoneEditor`, you've implemented `setAsTest`, rather than overriding `setAsText`. As a result, Spring is calling the `setAsText` implementation in `PropertyEditorSupport`, which throws the exception.

This is why you should *always* use `@Override` annotations, and set your compiler to at least report a warning if you don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have a typo in your class. It's setAsText, not setAsTest:

```
@Override
public void setAsText(String textValue) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    final String stripped = stripNonNumeric(textValue);
    final String areaCode=stripped.substring(0,3);
    final String prefix=stripped.substring(3,6);
    final String number=stripped.substring(6);
    final Phone phone=new Phone(areaCode,prefix,number);
    setValue(phone);
}
```

(always use @Override, as skaffman suggested)